# Spring - front can't call micro service after adding token

Tags: java, angular, spring

Problem with CrossOrigin. Frontend doesn't see backend.
I can call controller in gateway, but I can't call another controller from another micro-service.

I add @Bean to main class for another micro-service

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@EnableFeignClients
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class InfoApplication {

@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer CorsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry
                    .addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedHeaders("*")
                    .allowedOrigins("*")
                    .allowCredentials(true);
        }
    };
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(InfoApplication.class, args);
 }

}
```

But maybe, in addMapping I should write application-name?

```
.addMapping("/app-name/**")
```

like this?

My controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/info")

public class InformationController {

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@GetMapping("/all")
public PaginationObject findAll(@ApiParam(hidden = true) @RequestParam Map<String, String> allRequestParams) {
    return Service.findAll(allRequestParams);
}
```

Postman:
[image]

Comment: please show your controller method that is handling the request as well as how you are sending the request(postman, browser, curl?)

Comment: I added my controller, thank you!

Comment: What does your browser consol say? CrossOrigin error? But does your frontend recognize an endpoint?

Comment: @k-wasilewki, telling nothing. I can't see anything in console on my backend. But for the gateway, I see. I don't see for another service